# How to use CONCAT?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, syntax-error, group-concat

I'm a beginner at SQL and I'm struggling to understand how to use the CONCAT function. Can someone provide some guidance or resources that can help me properly learn how to use this function effectively in SQL?

I am working on a project for my google class for a database. I've been trying to learn how to use the CONCAT function in SQL, but I'm having difficulty understanding how it works and how to apply it to my datasets. I've tried reading some tutorials online, but I'm still not clear on how to use it effectively in practice.

Comment: The duplicate offers plenty of advice as well as links to the documentation

Comment: If you have a specific problem you should publish it.

Comment: It is hard to grasp what is there to understand. You have strings. You glue them together. Not often used, but e.g. for names `concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)`. In standard SQL we would use the string concatenation operator `||`, but MySQL doesn't support it (and uses the double pipe as the logical OR operator instead), so they have provided the function `CONCAT` for this.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner SQL Server also doesn't use `||` and the function `CONCAT` exists in all RDBMS I know. So the question is what is more "standard" ;) What I don't understand is why Oracle doesn't allow to use more than two arguments in `CONCAT`. That's one of the strange "Oracle things" as was the "dual" we don't need no longer in the new Oracle versions.

Comment: Well, the string concatenation operator has been the `||` at least since SQL-92. Why MySQL didn't implement it, when it was first build way after 1992, is beyond me. SQL Server started in the late eighties, and it seems they were just not flexible enough even in their early years to switch to the standard operator. Oracle forced us to select from a one-row table, because standard SQL demanded to select from some table, and, well the misnomer `dual` has historical roots :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select concat('10');  
+--------------+  
| concat('10') |  
+--------------+  
| 10   |  
+--------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  
 
mysql> select concat('11','22','33');  
+------------------------+  
| concat('11','22','33') |  
+------------------------+  
| 112233 |  
+------------------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```